# Probability Density Function Equation, Multivariable Calculus

Tags: probability, integration, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals, density-function

I have the following problem:

The formula for the normal distribution has a π in it. In this simplified version of the normal probability density function, solve for C. The correct answer has π in it.

$$
1 = C\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dydx
$$

Can anybody tell me how to solve this problem? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Seeing $x^2+y^2$ in an integral like this should/may trigger something: have you tried to switch to polar coordinates?

Comment: Hint: change to polar coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You could do all of the integration, as the comments have pointed out. However, it is possible that you have been given as a fact, or proven in class that 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2}\,dt = \sqrt\pi.$$ Thus, use this fact twice:
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\,dydx
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2}\,dy\right]dx\\
&=\sqrt\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx\\
&=\sqrt\pi\cdot\sqrt\pi\\
&= \pi.
\end{align*}
This implies that $C = 1/\pi$.

Of course, this answer is invalid, if you are not allowed to use that fact.